# my function returns undefined in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

The is a problem in my function(ar), that makes this with int:

912165161

912 165 161 Ft

It works well everywhere except in IE. Why can it be?

```
function ft(ar)
{
    ar = ar.toString();
    var len = ar.length; //1234    
    var ret = "";
    var j = -1;
    for(var i = len-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        j++;
        ret = ar[i]+ret;    
        if(j == 2 || j==5 ||j==8)ret = " "+ret;    
    }
    return ret+" Ft";
}
var code ="{\"osszesen\":1208,\"egy_kep_ara\":53,\"kedvezmeny\":null,\"eredeti-ar\":1208}";
array = $.parseJSON(code);
int = array["osszesen"];
alert(int);
alert(ft(int));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9WLGF/13/

Comment: Can you show us your `code` variable contents?

Comment: please wait I make an example in Jsfiddle, maybe not this was the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to replace ar[i] to ar.charAt(i) because the first was not standard

Comment: +1 for answering your own question.  Note that it *is* standard now in ECMAScript 5th Edition, but it wasn't in ECMAScript 3rd Edition.  IE 8 and later support bracket notation for strings.